# Keyboard not registering input after replacement

Tags: keyboard, hardware, software

I just replaced my top case on my late 2016 MacBook Pro Touchbar. Trackpad and Touchbar both work, and I even get backlight on my keyboard, however it doesn‘t register any input when booted into Mac OS.
With the help of an external keyboard I logged in and set the FileVault to off, rebooted but that didn‘t help. Safemode is no help either. Deleted the .plist file, no luck here.
Strangest thing of all: While booting, it registers every keystroke (I can boot into diagnostics, reset SMC and NVRAM). But also when in recovery mode, it stops working again.
Any thoughts?

Comment: More details: The new topcase originally was a FR (AZERTY) keyboard layout, I changed the caps to match my German (QWERTZ) layout, as is my system language.